# How to receive a users input in a chatbot app that uses QnA maker services

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

chatbot response (see in yellow in attached image), was coming from QnA KB services, and users are supplying input to botapp accordingly (blue colored).

[image]

What we want is to be able to to take the users input like `tutul#tutul@gmail.com#12/28/2018` into a variable, split with `#` character, trigger an email method (by C#.net) and then restrict to again go to KB services.
How the above can be achieved?

the existing code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than request the user enter multiple pieces of information delimited by '#', you could request each piece of information individually.  But, if you prefer to keep this format, something like the following should get you started:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    private const string UserInfoRequestText = "YEP! Let's do that. \n\n\n\n Can you share with me below information's: \n\n\n\n 1) What is your name? \n\n\n\n 2) What is your email? \n\n\n\n 3) Date of Meeting (MM/DD/YYYY)? \n\n\n\n Share the information for future proceeding as example like below \n\n\n\n \"sujan#sujan@gmail.com#12/30/2018\"";

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        IMessageActivity message = await result as IMessageActivity;

        if (!context.UserData.ContainsKey("userinfo"))
        {
            PromptDialog.Text(context, AfterUserInfo, new PromptOptions<string>(UserInfoRequestText));
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Forward(new QnADialog(), AfterQnAMaker, message, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }

    private async Task AfterQnAMaker(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        //allow the user to rate the qnamaker response here
    }

    private async Task AfterUserInfo(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        string text = await result;

        var values = text.Split('#');
        if (values.Count() < 3)
        {
            PromptDialog.Text(context, AfterUserInfo, new PromptOptions<string>(UserInfoRequestText));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
            userProfile.Name = values[0];
            userProfile.Email = values[1];
            userProfile.Date = DateTime.Parse(values[2]);
            context.UserData.SetValue("userinfo", userProfile);

            await context.PostAsync($"Thanks {userProfile.Name}. What can we help you with?");

            SendEmail(userProfile);

            //context.Call(new QnADialog(), );
        }
    }

    public class UserProfile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    private static void SendEmail(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", userProfile.Email);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        mail.Subject = "Email Subject";
        mail.Body = "Email body";

        //todo: actually send the email
        //client.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Note: the default dialog should not be a QnAMaker dialog.  This allows you to control what is sent to QnAMaker.

Comment: Thanks for response @Eric Dahlvang.
I want to use QnA KB services and want to take the user input as "tutul#tutul@gmail.com#12/28/2018" and split it and trigger the email section.
I can see in our existing  code(C#.net) 'RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync' method 
 responsible ,when  every time response is coming back from QnA KB services.

Comment: @AnirbanGoswami Yes, you can call QnA Maker within the if(results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty) block

Comment: Thanks for response @Eric Dahlvang.
Can u pls check my code that i uploaded now  and please give some suggestions.

Comment: Oh, you are using BotBuilder V3.  The code I've provided is for V4, and there is currently no QnAMakerDialog for V4 but the service is just called directly.  I'll change my answer to V3.

Comment: Edited with a BotBuilder V3 dialog.

Comment: Manyyyy Thanks @Eric.. Happy new Year 2019.
We want to switch user Input dialog and KB services dialog.. Like, after sending email we want to start QnA chat  bot response from KB services.
Can you pls help us with sharing some code sample.(BotBuilder V3 dialog+C#.net)

Comment: @AnirbanGoswami Please ask a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/botframework